# Splitting a QString by delimiter into multiple QStrings?

Tags: c++, qt, split

I know this is a simple question and can be done easily in python, but I just couldn't remember the keyword to look for.

I have a `QString`, `QString line = "id: John"`, I want to split it by the delimiter `:` and store them in two QString instead of a `QStringList`

```
QString line = "id: John"
QStringList elements = line.split(':');
```

I want a one liner of something like this so I can refer them with meaning names instead of `elements[0]` and `elements[1]`.

```
QString title, name = line.split(":");
```

Comment: Write an own function which executes QString::split() and returns the two values with [structured binding](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding)

Comment: @chehrlic Could you write an actual answer with that? I'm unsure how to reasonably do what you suggest.

Comment: @hyde: What do you want me to write? The function can e.g. return a std::pair<QString, QString> and those two can then be unpacked to 'line' and 'name'. See for example [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/structured-binding-c/)

Comment: @chehrlic Answering in comments is bad form here (other SE sites actively delete comments which try to answer). An actual answer would include the code in the question, augmented and modified so the question is answered.

Comment: @hyde: feel free to delete it - I don't care. I did not answered the question, I just gave a hint how to fix the problem, the op should still think by themself.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to say when you say

> I can refer them with meaning names instead of `elements[0]` and
> `elements[1]`

because you anyway have to unpack `QStringList` when you want to return a pair of `QString`

You could probably write a function like this

```cpp
auto stringListSplitter(const QString& str)
{
    QStringList elements = str.split(':');
    return std::make_pair(elements[0], elements[1]);
}
```

And you can use this as

```cpp
    QString line = "id: John";
    auto pair = stringListSplitter(line);

    QString title = pair.first;
    QString name = pair.second;
```

Comment: `elements[0]` and `elements[1]` is the way to retrieve the QStrings if I'm to store them into a QStringList after the split, which I don't want. Your solution is basically the same thing. I'm looking for a one liner solution like in python.

Answer (score 0):

As hinted to by chehrlic's comment, to get a nice one-liner, you need a little helper function, which converts the `QStringList` into something which can be used with [structured binding](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding). You can't use `QStringList` directly, because structured binding happens at compile time, and lists are dynamic structures with variable size. This whole mechanism requires C++17, so if you use a QMake project, you should add `CONFIG += c++17` to your pro file.

```
#include <QStringList>
#include <QDebug>
#include <utility> // for std::make_pair

auto getPair(const QStringList &strings) {
    // Since your strings seem to have extra whitespace, I added trimmed call.
    // The value method nicely returns default value if index is out of range.
    return std::make_pair(strings.value(0).trimmed(),
                          strings.value(1).trimmed());
}

void main() { 
    auto input = QStringLiteral("id: John");
    auto [title, name] = getPair(input.split(':'));
    qDebug() << input << "->" << title << name; return 0;
}
```

Comment: What if I want to split the QString to more than two elements?

Comment: @reddy Use `std::make_tuple` instead of `std::make_pair`. You need a separate function for that (or do some template magic to make compiler generate the different functions for you), because the return type of the function must be fixed at compile time.